# Water dispenser not working properly

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

In my world im trying to make Zombified Piglin gold farm. That requires turning a 23 x 23 nether portal with a flint and steel dispenser and a water dispenser for completing this mechanic. I got the fire part down but there is an issue with the water dispenser. It wont remove the water when the redstone signal turn off. To conserve flint and steel durability, I'm making the entire portal manual by flicking a lever on to activate and deactivate the portal once.

### What answer I'm looking for

I want to figure out how turn the water on and off with just one redstone signal just after the F&S dispenser activates the portal (activate and deactivate the portal when a redstone signal is recieved).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dispenser needs to be activated twice (once to place the water and once to remove the water) as the dispenser will not do anything just by depowering it.

You could do this by splitting the line that leads to the dispenser into 2 signals that are timed so that the first signal hits, then turns off and then a second later the second signal hits and turns off.

The first line would just need 1 repeater on minimum delay, the other line should be 3 repeaters on max delay and both could rejoin to one line before powering the dispenser. This will give 2 separate signals.

You could also use a pulse shortener to create a 1 tick pulse so that the signals can go to the dispense with less of a timing gap.